# calculate property based on another field using stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have below code which I want to convert to stream, it may not make sense to write such complex logic in parallelStream or stream but still wanted to understand how would we write this with lambda expression.

```
for(PositionModel position :positionList)
    {           
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        line.append(position.getInstrument());
        line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
        line.append(position.getAccount());
        line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
        line.append(position.getAccountType());
        line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);

        List<TransactionModel> tranList = transactionMap.get(position.getInstrument());
        int delta = 0;
        if(tranList != null )
        {

            tranList.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.gr)
            for(TransactionModel tran: tranList)
            {
                if(PositionCalcContant.BUY_INDICATOR.equals(tran.getTransactionType()))
                {
                    if(PositionCalcContant.EXTERNAL.equals(position.getAccountType()))
                    {
                        delta += tran.getTransactionQuantity();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        delta -= tran.getTransactionQuantity();
                    }                       
                }
                if(PositionCalcContant.SELL_INDICATOR.equals(tran.getTransactionType()))
                {
                    if(PositionCalcContant.EXTERNAL.equals(position.getAccountType()))
                    {
                        delta -= tran.getTransactionQuantity();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        delta += tran.getTransactionQuantity();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        line.append(position.getQuantity()+delta);
        line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
        line.append(delta);
        bw.write(line.toString());
        bw.newLine();

        position.setDelta(delta);

        if(Math.abs(delta) > maxChange)
        {
            maxChange = delta;
            maxChangeInstrument = position;
            maxChangeInstrument.setDelta(delta);
        }
        if(Math.abs(delta) < minChange)
        {
            minChange = delta;
            minChangeInstrument = position;
            minChangeInstrument.setDelta(delta);
        }
    }
```

There are 2 loops here I want to convert both to lambda or atleash the inner loop to lambda

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for streams as there are side effects and other stuff going on.

Comment: atleast the inner loop of transactionList?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something and came up with below, is this in anyway worse/better than the original code.

```
delta = tranList.parallelStream().collect
                    (Collectors.summingInt(model -> getDelta(model, position.getAccountType()))).intValue();

private int getDelta(TransactionModel tran, String accountType) {

    int delta = 0;
    if(PositionCalcContant.BUY_INDICATOR.equals(tran.getTransactionType()))
    {
        if(PositionCalcContant.EXTERNAL.equals(accountType))
        {
            delta += tran.getTransactionQuantity();
        }
        else
        {
            delta -= tran.getTransactionQuantity();
        }                       
    }
    if(PositionCalcContant.SELL_INDICATOR.equals(tran.getTransactionType()))
    {
        if(PositionCalcContant.EXTERNAL.equals(accountType))
        {
            delta -= tran.getTransactionQuantity();
        }
        else
        {
            delta += tran.getTransactionQuantity();
        }
    }
    return delta;
}
```

Also this is only for the inner loop where we are calculating delta, for the whole even I agree it would too much complex and may not worth it.

Comment: Are there other return values possible for `tran.getTransactionType()`? These nested `if` statements look heavily redundant, as you are ending up doing `delta ±= tran.getTransactionQuantity()` in either case.